# windsor ioc in console app

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I am working on a console application and I want to use castle windsor for di.  I have the following code in my Main method for the console app -

```
private static IWindsorContainer container;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter(new ConfigResource("castle")));
...
```

Here is my configuration file -

```
<configSections>
    <section name="castle" type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler, Castle.Windsor"/>
  </configSections>

  <castle>
    <components>
      <component
        id="myrepository"
        service="_123App.Repositories.IMyRepository, _123App"
        type="_123App.Repositories.MyRepository, _123App"
      />
    </components>
  </castle>
```

when I run the app, I get the following error -

```
Could not convert from '_123App.Repositories.MyRepository, _123App' to System.Type - Maybe type could not be found
```

Does anyone know what might be happening here?  I used reflector to ensure that the assembly names are correct and everything is where it is supposed to be.
Thanks for any thoughts.

EDIT - Here is the whole exception stack trace -

```
Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Conversion.ConverterException was unhandled
  Message=Could not convert from '_123App.Repositories.MyRepository, 123App._123App' to System.Type - Maybe type could not be found
  Source=Castle.Windsor
  StackTrace:
       at Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Conversion.TypeNameConverter.PerformConversion(String value, Type targetType) in e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Windsor\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\SubSystems\Conversion\TypeNameConverter.cs:line 91
       at Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Conversion.DefaultConversionManager.PerformConversion(String value, Type targetType) in e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Windsor\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\SubSystems\Conversion\DefaultConversionManager.cs:line 134
       at Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Conversion.DefaultConversionManager.PerformConversion[TTarget](String value) in e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Windsor\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\SubSystems\Conversion\DefaultConversionManager.cs:line 162
       at Castle.Windsor.Installer.DefaultComponentInstaller.SetUpComponents(IConfiguration[] configurations, IWindsorContainer container, IConversionManager converter) in e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Windsor\src\Castle.Windsor\Windsor\Installer\DefaultComponentInstaller.cs:line 196
       at Castle.Windsor.Installer.DefaultComponentInstaller.SetUp(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store) in e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Windsor\src\Castle.Windsor\Windsor\Installer\DefaultComponentInstaller.cs:line 52
       at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.RunInstaller() in e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Windsor\src\Castle.Windsor\Windsor\WindsorContainer.cs:line 314
       at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer..ctor(IConfigurationInterpreter interpreter) in e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Windsor\src\Castle.Windsor\Windsor\WindsorContainer.cs:line 87
       at _123App.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Username\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\_123App\_123App\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Can you post the _whole_ exception stack trace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Immediate fix would be to make sure the `_123App.dll` (or `_123App.exe`) makes its way into the output directory of your project.

In longer run, don't use XML and register the component in code.

Comment: I eventually got to the point of registering the components in code and that seems to be working.